# VS Code Project - can't find Antlr3.runtime file (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, antlr3, csproj

So we have a project I'll call **PrimaryProj** for discussion purposes.  We also have another project with the code for NCalc, the .NET mathematical expression evaluation system.

PrimaryProj uses a Project Reference to NCalc, such as:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x86;AnyCPU</Platforms>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <!--blah blah blah -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- <PackageReference Include="PrimaryProj.NCalc" Version="0.0.1" /> -->
    <ProjectReference Include="../../primary-proj/src/NCalc.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see, we previous used a PackageReference to a NuGet package, but are now trying to use a ProjectReference to our NCalc code in another project.

Now, the NCalc's csproj uses package references still, thusly:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x86;AnyCPU</Platforms>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <!-- redacted product info here -->
    <Description>
      NCalc is a mathematical expressions evaluator in .NET. NCalc can parse any expression 
      and evaluate the result, including static or dynamic parameters and custom functions.
      This library is derived from the original NCalc, released under the MIT License,
      Copyright (c) 2011 Sebastien Ros.
    </Description>
    <Copyright>U.S. Army</Copyright>
    <!-- blah blah blah --->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr3.CodeGenerator" Version="3.5.2-beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr3.Runtime" Version="3.5.2-beta2" />
  </ItemGroup> -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr3" Version="3.5.2-rc1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Antlr3.Runtime" Version="3.5.2-rc1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It originally used / tried to use the 3.5.2-beta2, but neither this, nor the rc1 work.  It did work when we had PrimaryProj's csproj file using PackageReferences instead of ProjectReferences.

Now we get an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Do PackageReferences and ProjectReferences have compatibility problems? (e.g., if one project uses ProjectReferences, the projects it references has to also?)

This has been a massive head-scratcher.  Also, the only place we've ever seen this version number 3.5.0.2 in the error above is in some ANTLRStringStream reference from inside of NCalc - we are able to use omnisharp-metadata, and this is where we see this version indicated.

This is all very confusing.  Any help, especially if you happen to deal with these types of .NET headaches, would be appreciated.

Comment: Do your projects reside in the same solution? When you had as a packageref that doesn't really matters but when you do as a projectref I think you need to have them in same solution. Anyhow, from your errormess it seems like your nugets from NCal doesn't work. There is no problem to mix project and package ref's.

Comment: Do you have to use NCalc? If not then I maintain this library which is built in .NET Standard with zero dependencies meaning it should be easy to use. https://github.com/bijington/expressive